# Why can i not increment this property?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I want to make a route in NodeJS which increment the property of a subdocument but I don't know how to do it and the way I am doing it now does not seem to work.

**blogPost model**

```
  const BlogPostSchema = new Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: (content) => content.length > 5,
      message: 'Content must contain at least 6 characters.'
    },
    required: [true, 'Content must be filled in.']
  },
  rating: Number,
  title: String,
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
  board: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'board'},
  comments: [commentSchema]
});

const BlogPost = mongoose.model('blogPost', BlogPostSchema);

module.exports = BlogPost;
```

**comment schema**

```
const CommentSchema = new Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: (content) => content.length > 5,
      message: 'Content must contain at least 6 characters.'
    },
    required: [true, 'Content must be filled in.']
  },
  user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user' },
  rating: Number
});

module.exports = CommentSchema;
```

NodeJS route

```
routes.put('/blogPosts/:id/comment/:idm', function(req, res) {
    const blogPostId = req.param('id');
    const commentId = req.param('idm');

    BlogPost.findById(blogPostId)
        .then((blogPost) => {
          blogPost.comments.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: commentId}, {$inc: {rating: 1}});
        })
        .then((blogPost) => res.status(200).json({
        'status': 'Comment rating is increased.'
    }))
    .catch((error) => res.status(400).json(error))
});
```

This is the response [Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCTeO.png)

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the promise hasn't been resolved, so what you can do is use async await functions or JavaScript generators which will make the client wait till the rating is incremented and the results json is sent.

Here's a tutorial on [async-await](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await) and [generators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ategZqxHkz4).